# Limiting database field values based on combinations of other fields

Tags: database

My task is to build a simple database to hold information on IT infrastructure at my work.

I know very little about databases, but it's not critical, it's only going to be used by my team. I can't go into the specifics as they're confidential and also somewhat technical, so I'll use a simple analogy.

Say I need to build a database holding information on various animals in an animal shelter. For the purposes of the analogy, each animal could easily have all its information held in a single table without redundancy. The fields for this table could be, say,

`ANIMAL_ID, ANIMAL_NAME, SPECIES, NUMBER_LEGS, NUMBER_TOES...` (bear with me, here).

Now, lets say this shelter only keeps `two species, dogs and birds`. Obviously you can limit `NUMBER_LEGS` to accept values from `0-4` only. However,

*in the case of birds, they would never have more than two legs*.

*Similarly, a bird with only one leg (the other having been bitten off by a dog) would only have a maximum of 3 toes rather than the usual six (whereas a dog might have anything from 1 to twenty toes)*.

I plan to have a limit on this at the application (or even presentation) layer of the program that will access this data. It will take the form of a decision tree

(eg. `choose animal, then choose number of legs, then number toes, etc`). However, I am wondering if:

A) If it is typical to enforce these constraints at the data level, so that it is impossible for the database to hold, say,

*a bird with three legs, or a three-legged dog with 20 toes*.

B) **If A is true, how would I go about doing this in a generic relational database?**

(Note that although number of toes and number of claws are both numerical fields, this will not always be true in the real thing. I might need a set of a certain attribute (say `ANIMAL_COLOUR`), where possible values are `BLACK, BLUE, RED, PURPLE, BRINDLE` etc. But **then a DOG cannot have the COLOUR value PURPLE**; meanwhile a *BIRD can be PURPLE or BLUE but not BRINDLE*.)

Comment: Thanks, Black_Crown, for cleaning that up for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are known as [check constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_Constraint). An example for Oracle is:

```
create table ANIMALS
(
  ANIMAL_ID     number
 ,ANIMAL_NAME   varchar2(100)
 ,SPECIES       varchar2(100)
 ,NUMBER_LEGS   number
 ,NUMBER_TOES   number
 ,constraint NUM_TOES_CK check(NUMBER_TOES <= NUMBER_LEGS * 3)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, John. I've researched this and found there are keywords like CASE and WHEN and THEN that might help me; they seem to allow declarative versions of if/then/else statements.
Only problem is that, as my rules are effectively a decision tree, where the values of a child node depend on the value of its parents, and also transitively on its grandparents and greater ancestors, this is going to mean a hell of a lot of cases and constraints.
Anyone know of any alternatives? I had an inkling that it might be possible to restructure the database, but I don't know where to start...